# How To prevent user from entering anything other than positive numbers in TextBox

Tags: c#, regex, xaml, uwp

I am developing a `UWP` app where i need to make sure that the user couldn't enter anything except Positive integers with a max length of 8 characters followed by a `decimal` and two more `digits`.
The `Examples` could be

```
12345.50,
123456.50,
123.23
```

I have to implement these on a `TextBox`. I would like to make sure that the `Shift` key cant be used on the keyboard and the numbers have to be entered from the `Numeric` keyboard`(both)`

I wrote this code , but its accepting special characters and `shift` key.

Lets assume that there is only one mode of input and that is via only the `keyboard`

```
 private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((!char.IsControl(Convert.ToChar(e.Key)) && !char.IsDigit(Convert.ToChar(e.Key)) &&
      (Convert.ToChar(e.Key) != '.')))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is jot a real-world scenario. You cannot prevent the user from entering data other than by keyboard: speech, ink, IMEs, autosuggest, etc. will all enter text in your TextBox without going through the KeyDown event.

The only way to ensure the TextBox gets only your valid format is after the only is received: in TextChanging, TextChanged, LostFocus, submit-button input, etc.

Since hit acceptance requirement is self-contained TextChanging is probably the best place: make sure the text is allowed and remove and characters which are invalid. Be careful not to be so restrictive that the user can't get to valid input: don't reject a "." that isn't followed by two digits before the user can enter those digits.

An other option (much better if two fields depend on each other) is to let the user make invalid input but tell them: leave the bad input, but mark it invalid and don't accept the form until it has been fixed.

Also take a look at the TextBoxMask property in the UWP Community Toolkit at http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/TextBoxMask/

Comment: I have read your answer about the similar question posted on MSDN as well. The fact is this UWP app will have its input using only the keyboard provided by the OS